# How to filter sqlite records for the last 24 hrs?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am developing an windows store application in which am using SQLite. I want to filter the records for the last 24 Hrs,48 Hrs and for a week.I am having a datetime field in the table but when I am providing the query below it gives an exception.Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I am trying it to filter for the last 24Hrs.

```
var query = (db.Table<Table Name>().Where(c => c.DateField > 
                                          System.DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)));
```

How to do this?

Comment: `db.Table().Where` should be `db.Table.Where....`. --- May be

Comment: Try and write it out in plain SQL instead - that is going to make it much easier for us to advice you.

Comment: DataField is NOT NULL ? Otherwise add && c.DateField != null

Comment: It works fine when I am passing System.DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1) as the parameter to this method.